# Log-normal doesn't fit the data in python

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting

I have a two arrays X and Y whose loglog plot gives me a log-normal like distribution for which I would like to do a fit. My code is as follows:

```
import yt
from yt.units import kpc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import yt.visualization.eps_writer as eps
plt.switch_backend('agg')

filename="/lunarc/nobackup/users/samvad/FINAL-50-0.5/output/output_00029/info_00029.txt"
ds=yt.load(filename)
ds.define_unit("H", (1.674*10**(-24), "g"))
ad=ds.all_data()
dens=ad.cut_region(["obj['density'].in_units('H/cm**3') > 0"])
profile = yt.data_objects.profiles.create_profile(dens, [("gas","density")], [("gas","cell_mass")], weight_field=None, fractional=True)

X=profile.x.in_units("H/cm**3")
Y=profile[("gas","cell_mass")]

p=plt.loglog(X, profile[("gas","cell_mass")], 'b', label='139.05 Myr')

def fit_func(x, mu, sigma):
        return (np.exp(-(np.log(x)-mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
pfit, perr = curve_fit(fit_func, X, Y)
XX=np.logspace(-2, 6, num=100)
p=plt.semilogx(XX, pdf, color='b', linestyle='dashed')
```

However, I don't get a proper fit to my data.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVVGF.png)

[Here is the link to my data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vcq1G1A0VxrUHrzxqGAZOmKHRYWjXRfL?usp=sharing) (output_000029) and could someone please shed light on what probably is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data file?

Comment: I edited to add link to the data.

Comment: The link has only .png files with no file named "info_00029.txt" as in your code.

Comment: there is a folder named output_00029 on the top inside which there is the .txt file. The entire output is needed to process the data though.